# Winforms: Is there a way to put some space between image and checkbox in treeview?

Tags: .net, winforms, treeview

I'm creating a Treeview in Winforms and within this TreeView, I'm using both images, and checkboxes.  In the end result the images are so close to the check boxes that they almost touch.  Is there a way to put a couple of pixels worth of blank space between the image and the checkbox.  If possible I'd like to avoid custom painting, but if that does happen to be the only way, can you point me in the right direction to do the painting?

I tried adding a few (5) pixels to the left side images after I downloaded them and I it still looks weird.  Does anybody have any advice on how to custom paint the tree?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An obvious way to get more space is to use an image that has empty pixels at the left :)

Comment: @Hans Unfortunately I have no control over the images.  I'm pulling them from servers which I also have no control over.  Maybe I could do some post processing on the images to add the pixels though.  I'll look into that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This snippet is how I used to workaround the issue.

```
        Point destPt = new Point(6, 0);
        Size size = new Size(22, 16);
        tv.ImageList = new ImageList();
        tv.ImageList.ImageSize = size;
        foreach (String imgKey in imgListSrc.Images.Keys)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.DrawImage(imgListSrc.Images[imgKey], destPt);
            g.Dispose();
            tv.ImageList.Images.Add(imgKey, (Image)bmp);
        }
```

Comment: Excelent! 

Just manage the original image list as usual and run the code like this in the OnLoad event. 

Assign the new and modofied imagelist to the treeeview Imagelist property.